# Getting Unauthorized Error after configuring the custom HttpServiceHealthMonitor in Tridion Application Monitoring Service

Tags: core-service, monitoring

I have created a simple page which will give the "true" status of publishing queue when it is stuck for any reasons for last 15 minutes.

**Sample code below:**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XNamespace tcm = "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0";
            using (TridionCoreServiceClient client =  Common.GetNewClient())
            {
                PublishTransactionsFilterData filter = new PublishTransactionsFilterData
                {
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15)
                };

                IEnumerable<XElement> transactions = client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter).Elements(tcm + "Item")
                    .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Attribute("State").Value, "10") || String.Equals(t.Attribute("State").Value, "16"));

                if (transactions.Count() > 0)
                    Response.Write("true");
                else
                    Response.Write("Publishing Running successfully");
            }            
        }
```

Now when configuring in "cd_monitor_conf.xml" I have added below under

```
<ServiceHealthMonitors>
        <HttpServiceHealthMonitor ServiceType="Publishing Queue Alert" ServiceInstance="local" PollInterval="5m" TimeoutInterval="30s">
            <Request URL="http://localhost/MonitoringView/GetPublishingQueueStatus.aspx"/>  
            <Authentication Scheme="NTLM" Host="MYHOST" Domain="MYDOMAIN" Username="XXXX" Password="XXXXX"/>
            <Response SuccessPattern="Publishing Running successfully"/>            
        </HttpServiceHealthMonitor> 
</ServiceHealthMonitors>
```

I am getting below error in logs files

```
2014-01-28 09:30:49,821 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001 Service Publishing Queue Alert#local - Health check failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
2014-01-28 09:30:50,806 DEBUG HealthCheckResultEventHandler - TMA-PO-00000 HealthCheckResultEventHandler - Updating status for Publishing Queue Alert#local with id 1
2014-01-28 09:30:50,806 INFO  ServiceStatusStore - TMA-AG-99999 Status of service 'Publishing Queue Alert#local' changed to Error
```

**Webservice Response:**

```
<ServiceStatus><ServiceType>Publishing Queue Alert</ServiceType><ServiceInstance>local</ServiceInstance><ProcessId>-1</ProcessId><Status>Error</Status><StatusChangeTime>2014-01-28T06:27:21Z</StatusChangeTime><LastReportTime>2014-01-28T06:26:18Z</LastReportTime><MonitoredThreadCount>-1</MonitoredThreadCount></ServiceStatus>
```

Can we avoid giving the authentication? or anything I am missing to put here or any changes in my code would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be MTSUser or similiar rights, I have change the user details and all fine now!!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just for clarification, are you using just a normal domain account for this, or are you using the MTSUser account (or similar)? Does the account need to have any special permissions on the server?

Comment: It should be MTSUSer or similiar